# siunitx package crashes document

Tags: siunitx

Attention: I'm sorry to be such a novice with LaTex.

I am using my Uni's template for my research paper. I am having to use micrometers a lot, and reading through the forum posts here it seems like I should be able to just use `\usepackage{siunitx}` then say `\SI{1.55}{\micro\metre}` (taken directly from the best answer of another post) in the document. However if I add this to the start of the document it all goes to hell (short list of errors given in image). The only difference from working to this is the use package, and it happens in both compilers I have. I have included the code down to line 34 where it seems to take issue with the main document.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{uefrep}
%
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{cite,url}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage[tbtags]{amsmath}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{ae,aecompl}
\usepackage{bookmark}
%\usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx} %uncomment for thesis
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=red,urlcolor=cyan,breaklinks=true}
%\usepackage{pdfpages} %optional for inserting multipage pdf files to document
%
\pagestyle{plain}
\bibliographystyle{uefunsrt}
\setlength{\textheight}{20.7cm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{15.0cm}
\setlength{\hoffset}{-2mm} % Because the location of left margin depends on the printer, adjust this so that the left margin is 32 mm.
%\setlenght{\voffset}{2mm} % If necessary, adjust the top margin to 45 mm with this parameter.
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}
%
\begin{document}
%
\pagenumbering{roman}
%
\input{report_front}
\newpage
\input{report_abs}
%\newpage                   %Uncomment this command if you add a preface
%\input{report_preface}     %Uncomment this command if you add a preface
%
```

[image: Screen snip from compiler]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. The first error is likely the cause of the other errors: your package `l3kernel` is too old, and you need to upgrade it to be able to use `siunitx`. Don't forget to update MiKTeX in user and admin mode.

Comment: You don't need to be sorry to be a novice. The first error in your screenshot says "l3kernel too old". That means you should update your miktex system - do it with the miktex console in user *and* admin mode.

Comment: I note you have `\usepackage{ae}` which is a bit odd it was a temporary package useful at the turn of last century before scalable versions of the ec fonts were available, it's not often seen now. (Unrelated to your error messages though) also if you are using pdflatex (or even if you are not) delete `[dvips]` from `\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}` the package will select the right option without it being specified.

Comment: See for example https://miktex.org/howto/miktex-console.

Comment: You may be interested in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/35864. (You will have to update MikTeX in Admin and in User mode, this is explained in the link.)